# Importing dependencies for angular2-oauth2

Tags: node.js, angular, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get started with the npm angular2-oauth2 package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-oauth2

I've included several dependencies inside my systemjs.config.js:

```
 // map tells the System loader where to look for things   
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-oauth2':            'node_modules/angular2-oauth2', // <- library I'm trying to use
    'base64-js': 'node_modules/base64-js/lib/b64.js',
    'js-base64': 'node_modules/js-base64/base64.min.js', // <- Problem here
    'sha256': 'node_modules/sha256/lib/sha256.js',
    'convert-hex': 'node_modules/convert-hex/convert-hex.js',
    'convert-string': 'node_modules/convert-string/convert-string.js'
  };
```

As soon as I'm trying to include the "js-base64" library, I get an exception when opening the page:
`zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/buffer 404 (Not Found)`

How do I have to import this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after including several more libraries. I don't understand why angular is not automatically resolving the dependencies of the angular2-oauth2 plugin itself. Here is the working declaration map:

```
 var map = {
'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
'@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
'angular2-oauth2':            'node_modules/angular2-oauth2',
'base64-js': 'node_modules/base64-js/lib/b64.js',
'js-base64': 'node_modules/js-base64/base64.js',
'sha256': 'node_modules/sha256/lib/sha256.js',
'convert-hex': 'node_modules/convert-hex/convert-hex.js',
'convert-string': 'node_modules/convert-string/convert-string.js',
'buffer': 'node_modules/buffer/index.js', // added
"ieee754": "node_modules/ieee754/index.js", // added
"isarray": "node_modules/isarray/index.js" // added
```

};